# Freetype-config not found error when we install gd in php7.2-apache in Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to install the image php:7.2-apache from a Dockerfile, 
but I have problem in gd configuration.

I have installed the latest version of docker toolbox 18.09.3 from the page https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v18.09.3 because I have Windows Home 10

The content of the Dockerfile is the following

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

I have this error **configure: error: freetype-config not found.** during the construction of the image

```
checking for the location of libwebp... no
checking for the location of libjpeg... /usr/include/
checking for the location of libpng... no
checking for the location of libz... no
checking for the location of libXpm... no
checking for FreeType 2... /usr/include/
checking whether to enable JIS-mapped Japanese font support in GD... no
If configure fails try --with-webp-dir=<DIR>
checking for jpeg_read_header in -ljpeg... yes
checking for png_write_image in -lpng... yes
If configure fails try --with-xpm-dir=<DIR>
configure: error: freetype-config not found.
Service 'apache_php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libpng-dev     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to the reply from https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/865#issuecomment-511163936
firstly you have to patch and fix the php bug (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76324)

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pkg-config patch
ADD https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/freetype.patch?h=packages/php /tmp/freetype.patch
RUN docker-php-source extract; \
  cd /usr/src/php; \
  patch -p1 -i /tmp/freetype.patch; \
  rm /tmp/freetype.patch
```

then using the following cmd :

`RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/`

I have verified it's working for php7.2-fpm

Comment: I have tried in php:7.2-apache and it works correctly. Thanks

Comment: this package is down "freetype.patch"

Answer (score 4):

This issue is extensively clarified in the related GitHub issue, see in particular [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57046857/freetype-config-not-found-error-when-we-install-gd-in-php7-2-apache-in-docker).

In brief, the whole issue is related to a change in the default Debian version. Rather than applying patches or taking more complex routes, all that is needed is to add reference to `stretch` in the FROM line at the beginning of the Dockerfile. In this case, the first line should read:

```
FROM: php:7.2-apache-stretch
```

All else should work as expected.

Comment: this is the best solution, though I imagine it was not yet available at the time of the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me :

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    opcache \
&& docker-php-ext-enable \
    intl \
    opcache \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apt-get install -y zip unzip zlib1g-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: Where should I execute these 2 commands? In front of docker-php-ext-configure gd? and ./configure ?